# Configuring API user and Salesforce System User for Connecting multiple MC BUs to the same SF Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

Currently, we have one MC business unit (Parent BU) connected to one Salescloud and 4 other child business units
But for the future, we would like to connect 3 child business units to one Salescloud.
So we would like to know the best practices for MC Connect.
As you can see from the link below :
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5

using one Salesforce System user is recommended for 3 business units.

<example 1>

BU 1: MC API USER A <> SF User 1

BU 2: MC API USER A <> SF User 2

BU 3: MC API USER A <> SF User 3

<example 2>

BU 1: MC API USER A <> SF User 1

BU 2: MC API USER B <> SF User 1

BU 3: MC API USER C <> SF User 1

But when I searched from StackExchange and other websites, there seems to be many issues regarding this.
Could you recommend best practices for setting users for MC Connect?
I am confused whether example 1 or example 2 is best solution.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Are you planning to synch the same data sets to each child BU, or different data sets? Are users of child BUs allowed to see each other’s data? Those questions must be answered before deciding on one of the two apporaches.

Comment: No, we are trying to differentiate data set by countries so we will divide data by implementing flag field in SalesCloud. Also, users of child BUs will not be allowed to see each other's data unless they have access to see in Parent BU.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re going to differentiate data sets synchronized to each BU by using a Sales Cloud flag and in case the users are not allowed to see each other’s data, you will need to use the “[Scope by User](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_co_account_configuration_for_user_data_access.htm&language=en_US)” option when setting up Marketing Cloud Connect and you should have dedicated API user per each BU in Marketing Cloud and in Sales Cloud:

BU Parent User <> SF User

BU 1: MC API USER A <> SF User 1

BU 2: MC API USER B <> SF User 2

BU 3: MC API USER C <> SF User 3

When you configure the Salesforce connection in each BU separately, you will have to connect with a respective SF user, eg. when you configure BU2, you will need to integrate with SF User2 and in that BU, map the MC API User B to SF User 2. You will do that for each BU in Marketing Cloud.

Now when if comes to connecting in the direction from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud, you will need to have a SFMC user set up that has access to all integrated BUs in your account (eg. Parent, BU1, BU2, BU3) and use that user to connect from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud.

Only that configuration will allow you to separate data and use flags for filtering data sets differently in each BU.